# Geometry Nodes: Volume to Mesh, Keep polycount constant

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am generating a mesh that morphs from one object to another via graph shown in pic.
[image]

Is there a way to keep the polycount constant on the output mesh?
Can each vertex ID remain the same?

Idea is to then output multiple meshes using this method and use them as Blend shapes ultimately.

Comment: not really. at least with this method. you are essentially remeshing the objects.

Comment: I tried shrinkwrapping the geoNode mesh with a sphere - that seems to work for simple closed shapes. But that method fails when trying to shrinkwrap any mesh that has concave features.

Comment: k. that is understandable, but it's nearly important to keep the same poly count with this method.  Is there a specific reason you need the sand number of vertices?

Comment: end goal is to create a blend shape and use it in UE or Unity via vertex animated texture or some other form of storing vertex position data. For this to work the blend shape needs to be the same model, same vertex count, same vertex id.

Comment: in that case this might not be the right method for the job